# How to read files from wwwroot in Maui?

Tags: .net, directory, maui, wwwroot

In a maui blazor app I created the folder wwwroot/audio and put some files there. How can I get all the filenames from this directory?

```
        string mainDir = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory;
        var audioFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(mainDir, "/wwwroot/audio"));
```

Didn't work!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you can't get the file directly. But you can get it by reading the file. Such as:

```
 using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("wwwroot/audio");
```

I have done a sample to test and I can get the string in the txt file with a streamreader.
If you need more information, please check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#static-assets-limited-to-razor-components).

Comment: Yes I have found that approach in the .txt under -Resources-Raw-AboutAssets.txt. But I need a List of the FileNames that are in the Folder. Not the content of the file.

Comment: According to the [File system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=windows) in the maui, the wwwroot folder is [bundled files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=windows#bundled-files), so it seems no api to get this folder as a directory and get the file list of it. You can report this to the github. @nogood

Comment: I found that an exception occurred when the first slash in wwwroot was present, so I needed to change it to `"wwwroot/audio"`